# Unquoted special character ';' in pattern error using java.text.DecimalFormat

Tags: java, decimalformat

I try to use the java.text.DecimalFormat to format numbers like 123.456 to "+123.456" and -123.456 to "-123.456" by the help of a negative subpattern.

[see doku for DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

My pattern is:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("+#0.000; -#0.000;");
```

I get the error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unquoted special character ';' in pattern "+#0.000; -#0.000;"
```

What do i wrong?

Comment: Ok, i see my problem! The ending ; is too much! The correct pattern is of course -> "+#0.000; -#0.000"

Answer (score 1):

Mind the space between the positive pattern and the negative!  And the last semicolon should not be there.  Here's a pattern that works:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("+#0.000 ; -#0.000");
```

Does this help?